# How to scope out Services that implement interface X in standard MS DI?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, interface

I'm using a lib that is based around standard MS DI stuff (which I see for the first time and not familiar with). So far it wasnt anything complicated, I build Service Provider:

```
var services = new ServiceCollection()
                   .AddSingleton<StartupService>()
                   .AddSingleton<Service2>()
                   .AddSingleton<Service3>()
                   .AddSingleton<Service4>()
                   .BuildServiceProvider();
```

Then I start the app via StartupService

```
await services.GetService<StartupService>().InitAsync();
```

And I inject services via `ctor` in all the modules or other services that dependent on these:

```
private readonly Service1 service1;
private readonly Service2 service2;

public OtherService(Service1 s1, Service2 s2)
{
    service1 = s1;
    service2 = s2;
}
```

It is nothing special so far but as number of services grew and some of them required "warm up" my StartupService started to looked grim:

```
public async Task InitAsync()

{
    Service1.WarmUp();
    Service2.WarmUp();
    Service3.WarmUp();
    ...
}
```

So my ~~brilliant~~ dumb idea was to implement `IWarmUp` interface and just, like, iterate over service collection man:

```
foreach (var service in services.GetServices<IWarmUp>())
        service.WarmUp();
```

Obviously it didnt work.

Is there a simple solution to that without making some complicated system or rewriting all my existing `ctors` that already use injection? How can I get the services that implement specific interface so I can make them do contract job?

Comment: can't you do WarmUp in the service1 constructor?

Comment: No, my ctors are absent of any logic (it only used for easy DI) because some of that logic is pretty heavy and too ugly for ctor like DB load or async http data request. You wont be doing this stuff in ctor but it needs to be done during startup. Since quite a few services require it I decided to make it a pattern and use a `warmup` for some services instead of having a mess where one half is in `ctor` and another is in separate method and then you have headache reading it.

Answer (score 0):

You can register multiple implementations to a single service type - see [here](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-registering-multiple-implementations-interface). So, you could use reflection to find all the types implementing `IWarmUp`, then loop through them and register each type to that service type.

```
foreach( var warmUpType in myListOfTypesImplementingIWarmUp )
    serviceCollection.AddTransient( typeof(IWarmUp), warmUpType )
```

And then in `InitAsync` ask your `IServiceProvider` for an `IEnumerable<IWarmUp>` and loop through calling `WarmUp` on each object.

You can still register each type against itself like `AddSingleton<Service2>()` and then request it from DI as you're doing currently.

Comment: `.AddTransient` -- "Transient components are created every time they are requested and are never shared."  Sorry I must be missing something - if all my services work as a singleton (one instance) - how would it make sense to make transient instance of each if singleton ones that I inject are different instances? I need to warm up the existing services since they are intended to be permanent through app life.

Comment: Ah. Right. Well then you can just create the instances where you build up your `ServiceCollection` and call a different overload of AddSingleton -> `AddSingleton(sp => mySingletonOne)`. Then do the same for each as in my answer above where `myListOfTypesImplementingIWarmUp ` is created like `new List<IWarmUp>{ mySingletonOne, mySingletonTwo }`.

Comment: Think you can edit your answer to reflect what do you mean in some detail?